# watch not displaying output of script

Tags: bash, awk, watch

I have a simple script which just uses awk to extract some information from output of `ps`. When I run this on the terminal, it works fine. But, when I run this script with watch:

```
watch bench_run.sh
```

there is no output at all.

The script is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

bench_run() {
    local awk_cmd='
        {
            time=$10
            bench=$46

            start=match(bench, /throughput/)
            start+=(RLENGTH+1)
            end=match(bench, /base/)
            printf ("%s %s\n", time, substr(bench, start, end-start-1))
        }
    '

    ps aux | grep $USER | grep simulator | awk "$awk_cmd"
}

bench_run
```

What could be the reason for watch not printing any output?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `ps aux` by `ps auxww` to get the full width output.
`ps` is probably testing your input or tty and deciding to act differently
inside `watch`.

Comment: @Hashken: I think this is the correct (and most succinct) answer. Adding the `ww` to the option list makes sure you get the full command line printed out; otherwise, output gets truncated to your current window width.

Or as @cas suggests,  use `ps -o ` to control the output in a way that make it more awk friendly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the start of an improved version.  So far, I've changed it to:

- get rid of the `grep`s (`awk` can do regexp matching)
- make better use of `ps` options
- got rid of the strange awk_cmd local variable
- quote $1 and $46 (which is now $37 with 9 unwanted fields removed from `ps` output

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

bench_run() {

    ps -u "$USER" -o time,args | awk "/simulator/ {
            time=\$1
            bench=\$37

            start=match(bench, /throughput/)
            start+=(RLENGTH+1)
            end=match(bench, /base/)
            printf ("%s %s\n", time, substr(bench, start, end-start-1))
            }
    "
}

bench_run
```

Here's a version that uses `sed`

```
#! /bin/sh
watch 'ps -u "$USER" -o time,args | 
       sed -n -e "/[s]imulator/ s/\([^ ]*\) .*\(throughput.*\)base.*/\1 \2/ p"'
```

I've used `'` single-quotes around the watch command, so I've used `"` double-quotes around the sed command that's inside it.

If `simulator` is the full name of the process, you could use:

```
#! /bin/sh
watch 'ps -o time,args -C simulator | 
       sed -n -e "s/\([^ ]*\) .*\(throughput.*\)base.*/\1 \2/ p"'
```

Comment: could you add some more information about what exactly you are trying to do.  Is 'simulator' the exact full name of the process? or just an argument to the process name?  what are you trying to do with the start and end and substr() stuff?  i'm starting to think that this may be better done with `sed` than `awk`.  Is there any particular reason why you've embedded it in a function?  for re-use somewhere else?

Comment: Does `ps -u "$USER" -o time,args | sed -n -e '/[s]imulator/ s/\([^ ]*\) .*\(throughput.*\)base.*/\1 \2/ p'` give you the output you're after?

Comment: `simulator` is the name of the process

Comment: The above version with sed works :) But, how do I use this with watch? My original script also work fine when run alone. But, when given to watch it gives no output

Comment: @Hashken, i've added a version that uses sed to my answer.

Comment: I tried your script and was again getting no output. Using the sed command alone produces output. But, when run inside `watch`, no output is produced

Comment: it worked when i tested it.  is your `watch` broken? ancient version?

Comment: `watch -v` gives the output `watch from procps-ng 3.3.9`. Are you using a different version?

Comment: `watch from procps-ng 3.3.10`, but i wouldn't expect that to make much difference. only mention of watch in the changelog is that in 3.3.10 `watch supports new ANSI styles and background colors`

Comment: what kind of environment are you running in?  anything unusual? what terminal?  screen or tmux? my script works for me in screen, just tested it.